# select nothing in many2one widget

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I have a many2one field for which the selection of nothing (e.g. none, false, null) is a normal and valid state.

However the many2one widget in Odoo per default allows no empty selection. After a the record has been set, the user cannot unset the field with the normal widget.

Is there maybe some flag or Odoo feature that I can use to enable null selection?

Comment: Can you add some code examples? Usually there is no problem "unsetting" Many2one fields. Just delete out the content and save.

Comment: The `many2one` widget certainly allows empty values. You just delete the value and click outside the dropdown. Is that not working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the comments, an empty value is selected when all text in the many2one widget is removed and one clicks outside.

So you can select from the drop down an item. When you remove part of the items name, it is still selected. When you remove all text in the field, the selection changes to empty. I was not aware of this because I am used to having an empty row at the top or bottom in the drop down that represents the null selection.

Comment: wanted to answer this, but then you wanted to select 'nothing' (?) Why select nothing, when nothing is already selected by default? ;) But I was confused about this too. From the point of usability I found it strange to have to delete all characters in order to reset the field. But actually it's good behavior, since it rarely happens when you accidentially made an input you want to undo

Comment: I want to reset a (filter) field, so revert to the nothing selection. I agree that -although unintuitive- it is a good design because in 99.9% of cases the user wants to and should select a proper value, thus giving null as selection option might be bad user guidance. Because removing all characters is unintuitive, the user is doing this knowingly to revert a field

Comment: that's private, but: I do not know such a plugin. Here would be the place for a link ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign empty value for a `Many2one field` through code try this:

```
self._your_many2one_field = 0
```

And if you want to select blank in a `Selection field` try this:

```
 self._your_selection_feild = False
```